# Wordpress, как получить ссылку на страницу

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть задача, надо создать функцию которая будет возвращать ссылку на страницу.

Comment: опишите вопрос подробней, суть вопроса непонятна

Comment: Советую почитать о хуках:
 - get_permalink()
 - get_the_permalink()
 - the_permalink()
и что они делают.

Comment: @NikPashchuk Спасибо, сейчас попробую! У меня дело в том, что я смог вывести циклом **ссылку** на страницу. Но мне надо это сделать внутри другого цикла, другой таксономии. Когда делаю так как описал, то ломается вывод данных из базы первого цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную проблему решил при помощи функции:

```
get_page_link( $post, $leavename, $sample );
```